# Trying to use my own key for desCipher

Tags: java

I am using a key generated by keygenerator to create my desCipher object.  I would like to use a key I created, instad of being created by generateKey() methed
my code
  KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                myDesKey = keygenerator.;
                desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

Comment: `import standard.warning.DES_IS_BROKEN;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into SecretKeySpec

```
  byte[] binaryKey 
  byte [] encrypted
  SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(binaryKey, "DES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
  decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
```